# Counting parameters for the intersection of a quadric and a cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have to count parameters for the intersection of a quadric and a cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$, up to linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^3$.
I take account of the theorem according to which a not hyperelliptic algebraic curve $X$ of genus $4$ is such that the canonical map $\Phi_K$ embeds $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^3$ as a smooth curve of degree $6$ (by the vanishing of a quadratic and a cubic polynomial).
So I have:

number of parameters $=$  dimension of degree $6$ polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^3$ - dimension of  linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^3$ - 1. But this count doesn't give $9$, as I expect.
What's wrong?

Comment: Why should degree 6 polynomials be relevant?

Answer (score 3):

There are $9$ parameters of quadrics in $\mathbb P^3$, and $15$ parameters of automorphisms of $\mathbb P^3$.  Thus in your count, you may reduce to having a fixed quadric, which then has a projective automorphism group of dimension $6$.

There are $19$ parameters of cubic surfaces, but if we quotient out by the $6$ parameters in the automorphisms of our quadric, we are left with $13$ parameters.   Note that $13 = 9 + 4$; the point is that a canonically embedded genus $4$ curve is contained in a single quadric (which after a projective transformation we may as well take to be our chosen quadric), but is contained in a $4$-parameter family of cubic surfaces.

Comment: So I can answer in this way: since the quadratic polynomial describing the curve of genus 4 is unique, we can describe it, up to automorphisms, with 6 parameters. Now, for cubic surfaces, we have 19 parameters, but since we are intersecting with the quadratic surface, we substract 6. Now Miranda say that xF,yF,zF,wF and G vanish on X, where x,y,z,w are the projective space coordinates. Thus we subtract from 13 the dimension of $Span(xF,yF,zF,wF)$, and we have finished. Is it correct?